# Bash enter exter variables in command -exec bash -c

Tags: bash

**I got this script in bash tan recives 3 paramethers.**

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 3 ]
then 
    echo "Incorrect number of Paramethers"
    exit 1
fi

if ! [ -d $1 ]
then 
    echo "The first paramether is not a directory"
    exit 1
fi

nom=$1
cad1=$2
cad2=$3

find $nom/ -type f -exec bash -c 'printf "Arxiu:  {} \t NÚMERO: "; grep -o "[[:alnum:][:punct:]]*ad[[:alnum:][:punct:]]*en[[:alnum:][:punct:]]*" {} | wc -l;' \; | grep " [1-9][0-9]*$"
```

**I just wanna change the ad by the value of cad1 and the en by the value of cad2. How I can put inside the exe the 2 parameters. $cad1 and $cad2 doesn't work.** (In the last line, the first lines are working)

Comment: `$cad1` and `$cad2` won't be expanded in a string that is delimited by single quotes (`'...') you have to use double quotes. (`"..."`) You also have to escape the inner double quotes by `\"`. For example: `-c "printf \"Arxiu:  {} \t NÚMERO: \"; grep -o \"[[:alnum:][:punct:]]*${cad1}[[ ...`

Answer (score 0):

It's simpler and safer to pass arguments as arguments and then use positional parameters.

```
find "$nom/" -exec bash -c 'printf "Arxiu:  %s \t NÚMERO: " "$1"; echo "$2" "$3"' -- {} "$cad1" "$cad2" \;
```

Remember to quote variable expansions.